# Calabash android UITest Stalled error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, calabash

I've prepared UITest using calabash for Android. Test is working just fine on a local device, however when I'm trying to use Xamarin Test Cloud all I get is Stalled error:

```
2016-06-22 09:03:13 +0200 Validating
2016-06-22 09:03:23 +0200 Validating
2016-06-22 09:03:34 +0200 Validating
2016-06-22 09:03:56 +0200 Stalled error (support team notified)
2016-06-22 09:04:06 +0200 Stalled error (support team notified)
```

Why do I get such an error? Here's my calabash test code:

first.features file

```
Feature: First run feature

  Scenario: As a new user I can choose my region
    Given I am on choose region page
    When I press list item number 1 
    Then I touch the select button
    Then I shold see info
```

calabash_steps.rb file

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'calabash-android/calabash_steps'

Then(/^I am on choose region page$/) do
sleep(1)
end
Then(/^I touch the select button$/) do
touch("* marked:'selectButton'")
end
Then(/^I shold see info$/) do
sleep(3)
element_exists("* marked:'text1'")
sleep(10)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue, please refer 
[Facing "Stalled error " on Xamarin test cloud when Xamarin.ios Uitest ran from Xamarin Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804669/facing-stalled-error-on-xamarin-test-cloud-when-xamarin-ios-uitest-ran-from-x)

When I changed device phone to tablet on xamarin test cloud device selection, my error resolved, however I checked properties of project, those are pointed for Universal device (not specific to Phone/tablet)