# Facing "Stalled error " on Xamarin test cloud when Xamarin.ios Uitest ran from Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uitest, xamarin.uitest

I am facing "Stalled error" when running UITest on Xamarin test cloud from mac machine - Xamarin studio. UITest is written for Xamarin.ios application, which is just having code (the default code) AppLaunches test and code is app.Screenshot("First screen").
My BeforeEachTest looks like as below

app = Configureapp.ios.PreferIdeSetting().StartApp();

Inside xamarin studio, unit test window, I have linked the ios app to the UITest project.

My project is in configuration debug|iPhone.

I have followed steps as, in appdelegate file of ios project, I have added
Xamarin.Calabash.Start(), and also added package Xamarin.testcloud.agent in ios project.

My app size is 32.88 mb

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: you can reach out Xamarin support regarding this issue

Comment: I have not got the exact reason of the error however when I selected tablet (ipad) as device then my error resolved, previously I was selecting iPhone as device, at that time I got stalled error. I will re-comment if I got reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stalled Errors are typically an issue with a specific *(physical)* device on XTC.  The XTC bots will usually address the stalled device within a few minutes of a stalled detection.  Check your XTC dashboard later, the stalled test will probably finish on its own.

I beleive anything still *stalled* after the bots have a try will be automatically queued for investigation by the *(human)* XTC team.  They'll clean it up and finish the test run for you.

As [Prashant C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804669/facing-stalled-error-on-xamarin-test-cloud-when-xamarin-ios-uitest-ran-from-x#comment68839465_40804669) said in your question's comments, reach out to Xamarin Support to learn more...

Although 99% of the time it is just a single stuck device holding up the test.  I'd recommend waiting a day to see if the bots *(or worst case, the team)* clean it up for you.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Regul, my stalled error is resolved, when I choose different device, my error resolved.However your comment is valid, that error resolves automatically after waiting for certain time for the same device is you want on Xamarin test cloud or solution is change the device.   Also to add here, Xamarin test cloud support team is helpful to resolve the queries.